# Offset not working correctly

Tags: templating, entries

I have an entry that has a entries field where 9 entries have been added.

The first three entries are displayed in one block at the top of the page and this works correctly using .limit(3)

However further down the page I expect 6 entries to be displayed when using .offset(3). That is not happening. Instead you only see the next 3 entries, not the next 6. If I change to offset(6) I still see 3 entries but it's the final three entries.

Below is simplified relevant code.

```
{% for secondaryEntry in entry.secondaryFeatures.offset(3).all() %}  
  <li class="col-sm-4 feat-box">
    <div class="content">
      <a href="{{ secondaryEntry.url }}" class="img-container">
        {{ secondaryEntry.title }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Please advise.

**edit**
Here is the code calling the first three entries at the top of the page

```
{% for secondaryEntry in entry.secondaryFeatures.limit(3).all() %}
  <li class="col-sm-4 feat-box">
      more code
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and show how you're pulling in and displaying the first 3 entries?

Comment: @BradBell Have added in the code you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to reset your `.limit(null)` on the second call (the one with your offset) due to the way Element Queries work.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.